# Regex to pass Apache each line in logs file

Tags: java, regex, javac

I need to pass Apache log file through this regex but not working, return false.

```
private String accessLogRegex()
{
    String regex1 = "^([\\d.]+)"; // Client IP
    String regex2 = " (\\S+)"; // -
    String regex3 = " (\\S+)"; // -
    String regex4 = " \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\]"; // Date
    String regex5 = " \"(.+?)\""; // request method and url
    String regex6 = " (\\d{3})"; // HTTP code
    String regex7 = " (\\d+|(.+?))"; // Number of bytes
    String regex8 = " \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\""; // Referer
    String regex9 = " \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\""; // Agent

    return regex1+regex2+regex3+regex4+regex5+regex6+regex7+regex8+regex9;
}

Pattern accessLogPattern = Pattern.compile(accessLogRegex());
Matcher entryMatcher;
String log = "64.242.88.10 | 2004-07-25.16:36:22 | "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/Main/ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 1284 | Mozilla/4.6 [en] (X11; U; OpenBSD 2.8 i386; Nav)";

entryMatcher = accessLogPattern.matcher(log);
if(!entryMatcher.matches()){
  System.out.println("" + index +" : couldn't be parsed");
}
```

I've include the sample of Apache log, it's pip ("|") separated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use regexes? These are quite error-prone, easy to get wrong, and can be a maintenance nightmare...

An alternative might be to use a library for this, for example [this one](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser)

That said, if you do want to use a regex, yours contains a number of errors:

```
String regex1 = "^([\\d.]+)"; // while quite liberal, this should work
String regex2 = " (\\S+)"; // matches the first pipe
String regex3 = " (\\S+)"; // this will match the date field
String regex4 = " \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\]"; // date has already been matched so this won't work, also this is all wrong
String regex5 = " \"(.+?)\""; // you're not matching the pipe character before the URL; also, why the ?
String regex6 = " (\\d{3})"; // HTTP code
String regex7 = " (\\d+|(.+?))"; // Why are you also matching any other characters than just digits?
String regex8 = " \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\""; // Your sample log line doesn't contain a referer
String regex9 = " \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\""; // Agent is not enclosed in quotes
```

One possible regex solution *for the example log line you have given* is this:

```
String regex1 = "^([\\d.]+)"; // digits and dots: the IP
String regex2 = " \\|"; // why match any character if you *know* there is a pipe?
String regex3 = " ((?:\\d+[-:.])+\\d+)"; // match the date; don't capture the inner group as we are only interested in the full date
String regex4 = " \\|"; // pipe
String regex5 = " \"(.+)\""; // request method and url
String regex6 = " (\\d{3})"; // HTTP code
String regex7 = " (\\d+)"; // Number of bytes
String regex8 = " \\|"; // pipe again
String regex9 = " (.+)"; // The rest of the line is the user agent
```

Of course this may need some further tweaking if other log lines don't follow the exact same format.

Comment: Thanks @brain99, using the parser lib, i'm trying to pass time in this format yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss for `%{format}t`string.

Comment: If using the library I linked, sure - just configure the log format properly (I believe it should be something like `String logformat = "%h | %{%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S}t | \"%r\" %>s %b | %{User-Agent}i"`. You can then choose to either retrieve the date as a timestamp or have the individual fields in your POJO (year, month, day, ...)

Comment: Wow, You're the best... please can the above logformat work for ANY apache log file that is delimitered by pip. thanks

Comment: Well, the format needs to be correct for each logfile (so you cannot just have one logformat and expect it to perfectly parse just any random file you throw at it). That said, the configuration seems to be almost fully compatible with apache's options so you should be able to put together a logformat config for just about any logfile.

Comment: Thanks @brain99, i don't have any specific apache logfile, only working on assumptions, i've search online and see different apache log file, don't know which one to stick to. I'm working on a project that ask me to => `Create a java tool that can parse and load the given web server access log file to MySQL. The delimiter of the log file is pipe (|)` please any idea on how this can be achieve?

Comment: If you have a specific logfile that is given to you, you can look at the contents and try to create a matching logformat configuration manually. If the tool is supposed to be universal, perhaps you can make the logformat configurable or have the user provide it (eg through a GUI or as a commandline parameter)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155702/discussion-between-oyewole-a-samuel-and-brain99).